# What could a medieval people do with electricity?

Tags: technology, medieval, electricity

My world has magic batteries, created by an alien people. These theoretically have the power of a nuclear reactor, able to generate about a Gigawatt each, but you can lower the voltage and amperage to basically anything, just by adjusting some nobs.

With source of practically unlimited electricity, is there anything it could be used for? Maybe they could use it for powerful electric fences?

Comment: There is just too many things it could be used for. You can have something spin by itself. Which make it possible to automate stuff like mills for example. And maybe even start having horseless carriages. Defence, attack, even just chemistry and science, entertainment, innovation, recreation. There is so many things that electricity can be used for when you have unlimited supply of it. Medieval people definitely weren't stupid, they'd be able to work out the basics at first and then work towards more and more applications. Just like people already did at a later date.

Comment: The question as it stands now is open ended, thus not a good fit according to our [help]. Please rework it to give it narrower scope

Comment: *"My world has magic batteries etc."* **How many** such batteries are there? **Where** are they? **How big** are they? In **what form** do they output electric power? (AC or DC, at what voltage and so on.) (For example, a typical gigawatt power plant outputs AC power at 200 kilovolt. This is because the way our technology works, it is impractical to carry gigawatt power at lower voltage, because we don't have any conductors able to carry the current.) (In the limit, in our own history we always had **one** such source of power; but it was very big and very far.)

Comment: I love the idea of adjusting a [nob](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nob#h2), much more fun than adjusting a [knob](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/knob). Definitely stick with nob.

Comment: Without the rest of the knowledge, these batteries could be used as weapons and to torture people.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to ask what they *can't* do. Fire starters are probably going to be the first thing they figure out, and after that, really crude electric lights. With a gigawatt to play with, they'll almost certainly figure out some way to weaponize this. Whether they can produce wire of sufficient quality and fineness for electromagnets (and then electric motors) is a better question. You won't see anything like modern electronics for quite some time.

However, with a gigawatt to play with, one application they will almost certainly figure out is **resistive heating**. This is going to have a huge impact on any number of areas, from not needing fires to cook or heat your house, to being able to use metal- and glass-working methods that require very high heat.

I'd guess that a progression might go from simple fire starters (possibly with a lot of accidents at first), to small-scale heaters (think: stove, oven, room space-heater), to "industrial" applications. It will start with easier blacksmithing (and ceramic firing), but from there go on to casting of metals with higher melting points and high temperature smelting.

Answer (score 1):

One very significant thing this could lead to is a reduction in metal armor because, for  reasons, your medieval guys now have tasers. The lethal threshold as far as power goes is 100 mA, so unless you have an inordinately high voltage, in the 100gV+ range and a relatively low amplitude (W= VI or W=RII if I remember correctly) than you have a portable heart-stopper in a field of metal.

As the other answer mentioned, fires are easy to start with electricity, as well as advanced heating.

You won't see computers due to the vacuum development needed for it+silica.

These batteries can be made into a heat source for a boiler engine fit for a train potentially.

Comment: Oh, ouch... I didn't think about using them to drive a steam engine (not just trains, but also stationary engines driving mills and such). That's stupidly inefficient compared to just using an electric motor, but much, much easier to engineer given the technology of the day. They'd definitely do that also, which means you're probably looking at a full-on industrial revolution, *if* you have enough of the things. Give that a while and they *will* be able to make proper electric motors.